# Relationship between primes, right triangles and homogeneous polynomials

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers, divisibility

It is known that if $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ is a primitive Pythagorean triplet then $z$ is not  divisible by any prime of the form $4k-1$. The following is a generalization of this classical result which shows that the source of this property is not the hypotenuse $z$, but the two orthogonal side $x$ and $y$:

> **Conjecture**: Let $f(x,y) = a_0x^n + a_1 x^{n-1}y + a_2x^{n-2}y^2 + \cdots + a_ny^n$, $n \ge 2, a_0a_n \ne 0$. Then there are infinitely many primes of the form $8k+3$ which do not divide $f(x,y)$ for any primitive Pythagorean triplet $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$.

**Questions**:

1. Is the conjecture known? I am looking for a proof or disproof of the conjecture.
2. Or can we prove the simpler case for $x^n +y^n$?

**Update 1**: If has been proved for the special case $x+y$ (in the answer below) and is already known to be true for $x^2 + y^2$. Experimental data shows that $x^3 + y^3$ is not divisible by infinitely many primes of the form $8k+3$ while $x^4 + y^4$ is not divisible by infinitely many primes of the form $8k+3, 8k+5$ and $8k+7$.

**Update 2**: [Posted in MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/364896/primes-which-do-not-divide-certain-homogeneous-polynomials) since the general case of the conjecture is open

**Sagemath Code**

```
r = 2
fac = prime_factors(1)

while r <= 200:
    s = 1 + r%2
    while(s < r):
        if gcd(s,r)== 1:
            b = r^2 - s^2
            c = 2*r*s
            # t = 5*b^3 +7*b^1*c^2 + 5*b^2*c^1 + 2*c^3
            # t = b^4 - 3*b^1*c^3 - b^2*c^2 - 1*c^4
            # t = b^2 - 11*b*c - c^2
            t = b + c
            fac = fac + prime_factors(t)
            fac = list(dict.fromkeys(fac))
        s = s + 2
    r = r + 1

fac  = sorted(fac)
fac2 = fac
fac  = fac[:floor(0.5*len(fac))]
    
P = Primes()
prime = P[:prime_pi(max(fac))]

diff = list(set(prime) - set(fac))
diff = sorted(diff)
print diff
```

Comment: Your sequence $2,3,5,11,13,\ldots$ seems to be [OEIS sequence A042999](https://oeis.org/A042999).

Comment: Yes indeed. If true, it would imply that primes $\{2,3,5\}\mod 8$ do not divide the sum of the two orthogonal sides of any primitive Pythagorean triplet.

Comment: I would be interested to know how you came to this conjecture. It's a very interesting one.

Comment: @JessicaYatvitskiy The starting point was that I wanted to find a non-artificial sequence that had a very high density of primes. Since every prime of the $4k+1$ can be written as the sum of two primes so I thought the sequence $x^2 + y^2$ might be a good candidate. Then I thought it will be a good idea look at what the density of primes is in the sequence $x+y$ and so on ...

Comment: Very interesting and creative! Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 6):

For a primitive Pythagorean triangle, there are integers $m,n > 0$   with $\gcd(m,n) = 1$  and $m,n$ not both odd, so that $x+y$ equals
$$    m^2 + 2mn - n^2 $$
This is an indefinite binary quadratic form of discriminant $8,$ which has class number one. Thus the form is equivalent to $$ u^2 - 2 v^2, $$
and any prime $$  q \equiv 3,5 \pmod 8 $$
is not able to divide such a form without dividing both variables. The special case of prime $2$ is taken care of by the condition that $m+n$ be odd.

Comment: This for the cases $f(x,y) = x+y$ ? For $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ it is known to be divisible by primes of the form $8k+5$

Comment: @NilotpalKantiSinha yes, this is $x+y.$  Note that things would change just by throwing in constant coefficients, $x + 3y$  would not have the same problem primes as $x+y$

Comment: Your answer plus the fact that $x^2+y^2$ is not divisible by infinitely many primes of the form $4k−1$ can prove that there are infinitely many primes which do not divide $x^n+y^n$. Take the infinitely many primes which do not divide both $x+y$ and $x^2+y^2$. They will not divide $(x+y)(x^2+y^2)=x^3+y^3+xy(x+y)$. But we have no restriction on $x$ and $y$ so for every prime $p$ we will find some $x$ and $y$ such that $p|xy$. Hence the only option is that there are infinitely many primes which do not divide $x^3+y^3$. Similarly we can prove for higher powers.